# How to add / extend known symbols (function names,...) to Geany editor for autocompletion?

Tags: php, autocomplete, ide, geany

I am using Geany editor, mainly for PHP, Geany provides autocompletion for some languages (including PHP), but usually you don't create pure PHP scripts but use some base like a framework or a whole CMS. So it would be nice to have autocompletion also from functions from the framework/app core/cms.

Is there a way how to extend this symbol dictionary either manually add function headers or somehow tell it to dynamicaly scan some app-core directory to load it automatically?

Comment: @RAZERZ this question is not about what editor to use - it's about code autocompletetion in Geany and how to extend it's dictionary, most likely by somewhat-coding (even in conf. file). And Geany questions are often asked and answered here on stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geany :) 
- is there a better stackexchange site for this?

Comment: Shoot! My bad, I must have misread that at first. Yes you are correct, this should be the right forum for that question.

Comment: @RAZERZ I'm glad we've come to an undestanding - I really wasn't quite sure whether this is the right place :) I'm glad it is.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Snippets conf](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html) on the manual:

> Snippets are small strings or code constructs which can be replaced or
>   completed to a more complex string. So you can save a lot of time when
>   typing common strings and letting Geany do the work for you. To know
>   what to complete or replace Geany reads a configuration file called
>   snippets.conf at startup.

You can extend the defaut *PHP conf* or create a new *filetype conf* if you want to separate PHP behavior and your-CMS-specific behavior.

[Custom filetypes](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#custom-filetypes):

> At startup Geany looks for filetypes.*.conf files in the system and
>   user filetype paths, adding any filetypes found with the name matching
>   the '*' wildcard - e.g. filetypes.Bar.conf.

[Tags conf](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#symbols-and-tags-files) may be useful too:

> Upon opening, files of supported filetypes are parsed to extract the
>   symbol information (aka "workspace symbols"). You can also have Geany
>   automatically load external files containing the symbol information
>   (aka "global tags files") upon startup, or manually using Tools -->
>   Load Tags File.